# altering a variable outside a closure

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently encountering a problem. I have a function with an array which has items needing appending to. The items are appended in a closure inside the function and I can see the items in the array only inside the closure. Since the function has a return I need the appended items to be viewed by the function as a whole and not just the array. What can I do to solve this?

```
   var trueOrFalse: Bool = false
   var tempArray:[String] = []

   let reference_message = reference(.Append).whereField("delay", isEqualTo: 0)
           reference_message.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
               if error != nil {
                   print(error!.localizedDescription)
               }
               guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
               let documents = snapshot.documents
               if documents != nil {
                   for document in documents {
                       let messageID = document[kMESSAGEID] as? String
                       tempArray.append(messageID!)
                       //print(trueOrFalse)
                   }      
               }

        if trueOrFalse {
            if opened && trueOrFalse {
                print("Successful Walloping")
            }
        } else if !trueOrFalse {
            if !opened || !trueOrFalse {
                decryptedText = placeholderText
            }
        }

   return JSQMessage(senderId: userId, senderDisplayName: name, date: date, text: decryptedText)
```

Comment: What you are missing is the asynchrone concept. It's just that what I guess is what you call "outside", is just after the code you posted, is called BEFORE `tempArray.append(messageID!)`. Look for Swift + Closure + Async

Comment: Okay, I tried googling that but I still don't quite understand how it works. I understand the code I wrote as the return is executed before the closure and therefore the items won't be appended to the array. So I need to put everything on the same queue?

Comment: Reload your UI inside the closure after for loop.

Comment: can you please put the whole method's code as reference.

Comment: I posted the full code as an edit... Maybe I thought I could use Dispatchqueue.main.async? Or how would I be able to reload the UI, since the following function appears in a class and not a view